# The marker disappears depending on the scale and type of the marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to make the markers of a certain type disappear depending on the scale
I achieved that all markers would be switched off at a scale of <= 14
Tell me how to correctly write a condition for disabling markers with the type "ps1" for a scale <= 14

```
<script>

var markerType = {
    "ps1": [], "tp1": [], "rtp0": []
};

  function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.82034163, 31.19833049),
  zoom: 14,
        });
          var image =  {
          rtp0: {
          url: './image/rtp0.png',scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28, 40)},
          ps1: {
          url: './image/ps1.png',scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28, 40)},
          tp1: {
          url: './image/tp1.png',scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28, 40)},
};
          downloadUrl('phpsqlinfo.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');

                var icon = image[type] || {};              
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                icon: icon,
                map: map,
                position: point,
              });

    markerType[type].push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoomLevel = map.getZoom();

    for (var i = 0; i < markerType[type].length; i++) {
    var markers = markerType[type][i];

    if (zoomLevel <= 14) {
    (!markers.getVisible())
     markers.setVisible(false);
      } 
    else {
    markers.setVisible(true);
     }
    }

});
  });
     });

 }

 </script>
```

Comment: What is the error you get in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the markers' method to `setMap(null)` and `setMap(map)` when the `zoom_changed` event fires.

Store the markers you want to filter e.g ps1 in a variable:

```
var markersToShowHide = markerType.ps1;
```

Then add two functions, one to show the markers and the other to hide them:

```
function showMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markersToShowHide.length; i++) {
        markersToShowHide[i].setMap(map);
    }
}   

function hideMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markersToShowHide.length; i++) {
        markersToShowHide[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
var markerType = {
 "ps1": [],
 "tp1": [],
 "rtp0": []
};

function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.82034163, 31.19833049),
    zoom: 14,
});
var image = {
    rtp0: {
        url: './image/rtp0.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28, 40)
    },
    ps1: {
        url: './image/ps1.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28, 40)
    },
    tp1: {
        url: './image/tp1.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28, 40)
    },
};

    var markersToShowHide = markerType.ps1;

function showMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markersToShowHide.length; i++) {
        markersToShowHide[i].setMap(map);
    }
}   

function hideMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markersToShowHide.length; i++) {
        markersToShowHide[i].setMap(null);
    }
}

downloadUrl('phpsqlinfo.php', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
        var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');

        var icon = image[type] || {};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: icon,
            map: map,
            position: point
        });

        markerType[type].push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                        if (map.getZoom() <= 14) {
            hideMarkers();                              
                        } else {
                            showMarkers();  
                        }
        });
    });
});

}
```

Comment: I disabled all the markers. 
How to write a condition so that when changing the scale, only the markers with the type "ps1" are turned off, and the others markers were visible?

Comment: And with my fiddle you are not able to create a filter for ps1 markers? I thought it was clear. You are downloading an xml file from your server so you have the object with x number of arrays. Just pass the object with the array you are interested in as a filter. I am sure you want me to reproduce that as well, correct?

Comment: @NatalyKorgovskaya does the logic now make more sense?